# Dynamic Programming : True or False

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a conceptual doubt regarding Dynamic Programming:

```
In a dynamic programming solution, the space requirement is always at least as big as the number of unique sub problems.
```

I thought it in terms of Fibonacci numbers:

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
```

Here there are two subproblems, the space required will be at least O(n) if input is n.
Right?

But, the answer is False.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Not all dynamic programming problems require you to use extra space, and any top down with memoization can be converted to bottom up to prevent stack overflow.

Comment: @C.B. bottom-tup / top-down does not change space complexity in terms of big O notation, under worst case.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is indeed false.

For example, in your fibonacci series, you can use Dynamic Programming with O(1) space, by remembering the only 2 last numbers:

```
fib(n):
   prev = current = 1
   i = 2
   while i < n:
      next = prev + current
      prev = current
      current = next
   return current
```

This is a common practice where you don't need all smaller subproblems to solve the bigger one, and you can discard most of them and save some space.

Comment: True or False: If a dynamic programming solution is set up correctly, i.e. the recurrence equation is correct and each unique sub-problem is solved only once (memoization), then the resulting algorithm will always find the optimal solution in polynomial time.?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement Fibonacci calculation using bottom-up DP, you can discard earlier results which you don't need. This is an example:

```
fib = [0, 1]
for i in xrange(n):
    fib = [fib[1], fib[0] + fib[1]]
print fib[1]
```

As this example shows, you only need memorize the last two elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is not correct. But it's almost correct.

Generally dynamic programming solution needs `O(number of subproblems)` space. In other words, if there is a dynamic programming solution to the problem it could be implemented using `O(number of subproblems)` memory.

In your particular problem "calculation of Fibonacci numbers", if you write down straightforward dynamic programming solution:

```
Integer F(Integer n) {
  if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 1;
  if (memorized[n]) return memorized_value[n];
  memorized_value[n] = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2);
  memorized[n] = true;
  return memorized_value[n];
}
```

it will use `O(number of subproblems)` memory. But as you mentioned, by analyzing the recurrence you can come up with a more optimal solution that uses `O(1)` memory.

P.S. The recurrence for Fibonacci numbers that you've mentioned has `n + 1` subproblems. Usually by subproblems people are referring to all `f` values you need to calculate to calculate a particular `f` value. Here you need to calculate `f(0), f(1), f(2), ..., f(n)` in order to compute `f(n)`.